# how to mention a specific channel in a await message

Tags: discord.py

Problem: don't know how to mention a specific channel, it would be nice if some of you could help me
this code run but it doesn't mention the playground channel

```
@bot.command()
async def prov(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == 1028873503010717717:
        await ctx.send("The bot is disabled in this channel!,\n try in #playground")
    else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mention as in just display a clickable link/mention, just use <#channelid>

Eg: `<#1283768190123132>`